# How to change value of $() selector on fly to use it without reloading content?

Tags: jquery

I want to display hidden p[i] for each .cont[i] onclicked, and each event may appear only once.

html structure:

```
<div class="cont0">
  <p></p>
</div>
<div class="cont1">
  <p></p>
</div>
<div class="cont2">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

for this purpose i thought would be better to use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").hide();
  currentItem = 0;
  currentCont = ".cont" + currentItem.toString();
  mArrayList = ["a", "b", "c"];
  currentArrayElement = mArrayList[currentItem]; 

  $(currentCont).on("click", function(){
    $(currentCont + " p").fadeIn(3000).html(currentArrayElement);
    currentItem+=1;
  });
});
```

but after 1st oncklick, it can't find .cont1 as expected (for me)..
only one thing i found here - to redefine variables outside the function, i tried this:

```
nextCurrentItem = function nextCurrentItem() {
  currentItem += 1;
  currentArrayElement = mArrayList[currentItem];
};

changeCont = function changeCont() {
  currentCont = ".cont" + currentItem.toString();
};

$(currentCont).on("click", function(){
    $(currentCont + " p").delay(300).fadeIn(3000).html(currentArrayElement);
    nextCurrentItem();
    changeCont();
  });
});
```

but function's behavior is still the same. Also tried to add/remove class "selected" to next div - behavior is the same as previous.

Could you give me advice how to solve this problem (with 1 click on each element to invoke my event)?

Thank you!

Comment: currentCont only receives one event handler - that would be the first div. Instead give all divs the same class and attach to that class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only attaches the event to the first DIV.

Give the DIVs an ID and the same class to do this

```js
var mArrayList = ["a", "b", "c"];
$(function() {
  $(".fadeP").on("click", function() {
    $("p",this).fadeIn(3000).html(mArrayList[this.id.replace("cont","")]);
  });
});
```

```css
.fadeP>p { display:none }
#cont0 { border:1px solid red; height:50px }
#cont1 { border:1px solid yellow; height:50px }
#cont2 { border:1px solid green; height:50px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fadeP" id="cont0">
  <p>Paragraph 0</p>
</div>
<div class="fadeP" id="cont1">
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
</div>
<div class="fadeP" id="cont2">
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, @mplunjan, you're you savior :) added if statement for step-by-step-only use (if($(this).prev().hasClass("comp") || !$(this).prev())) and adding class("comp") for cliked 'this' element.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues. Only the first div is clickable, and there is a mixup of local and global variables because nothing is declared outside of the function blocks. Also it does not help that you have duplicated code.

Below I fixed all those issues:

```js
var currentItem = 0;
var currentCont = "";
var currentArrayElement = "";
var mArrayList = ["a", "b", "c"];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").hide();
  currentItem = 0;
  currentCont = ".cont" + currentItem.toString();
  currentArrayElement = mArrayList[currentItem];

  $('.clickable').on("click", function() {
    if (currentItem <= 2) {
      $(currentCont + " p").fadeIn(3000).html(currentArrayElement);
      nextCurrentItem();
      changeCont();
    }
  });
});

nextCurrentItem = function() {
  currentItem += 1;
  currentArrayElement = mArrayList[currentItem];
};

changeCont = function() {
  currentCont = ".cont" + currentItem.toString();
};
```

```css
div {
  border: solid 1px red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clickable cont0">
  <p></p>
</div>
<div class="clickable cont1">
  <p></p>
</div>
<div class="clickable cont2">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I only made the necessary changes to OPs original code, it is by no means optimal code.